# How much damage do zombies do?

Tags: dayz-2012

On average, how much damage does a hit from a zombie do?  Are there any status effects that change how much the actual hit does?

Answer (score 9):

From the [DayZDB](http://www.dayzwiki.com/wiki/Zombies):

> Zombie Damage
>
> - Zombies do little damage on their own but often cause status effects
>     like Bleeding, Pain or Broken Bones and occassionally Infection.
> - Zombies can knock you Unconscious in one hit if you're under 9000 blood or if the hit took you under 9000 blood
> - Zombie swarms attacking players in the building may very rarely destroy the building
> - Zombies can hit you (and you can hit them with a melee weapon) when they may appear to be too far away

In my experience, a single hit from a single zombie can cause anywhere between 50 and 100 damage. Should this damage knock you unconscious, there is a high likelihood the zombie will continue to eat you. This does a considerably higher amount of damage; ranging anywhere from 200 - 600 every one to two seconds.

There are no [status effects](http://www.dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Status_Effects) that will actively increase the damage a single hit will do. There are, however, status effects that will cause you to continually take damage after the hit has landed.

The very obvious one, **Bleeding**, will cause you to lose a large amount of blood in a very short period of time.

The second one, **Infection**, can very rarely occur when being hit by a zombie. Infection causes you to lose blood at a rate of 3 blood per second until you a) take **Antibiotics** (which are extremely rare), or 2) reach 6000 blood. Once you reach 6000 blood, you will lose blood at a slower rate.

I suppose it is technically possible for a lone zombie to kill you in a single hit, given the right circumstances. But... You'd have to be pretty unlucky for that to happen.

<sup>Any information not in block-quotes comes from my own personal experience as I roam the wastes of Chernarus</sup>